# Determine if the player should be able to interact with a door

Tags: 3d, linear-algebra

You know the drill, standard first person door mechanics. How do they do it?

My most noticeable and frustrating problem is when there is a door within range and in view, but the closest door is actually behind the player.

I'm aware of the "dot product trick" but say the player position is point 1, what is point 2? The center of the doors bounding box? The center of the open door way?

Any insight would be gold.

[image]

Comment: Do a raycast when the user clicks. The doors can be represented with a simple box.

Comment: I feel like none of these tags actually apply to this question. It is _not_ a game design question (read the tag), it is _not_ an OpenGL question since it has nothing to do with OpenGL, and it is not a _first person shooter_ question since it has nothing in common except the first person perspective... I'm not sure what to re-tag this question as though so I'll just remove all tags except for game-design for now. If you feel like this is wrong please revert my edit.

Comment: @Bálint raycast to where? I'm going for something traditional, where the player presses E vaguely in the direction of the door or open door way.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so when the player hits an "interact" button, this should trigger a search for interactable objects within range in front of the player character.

This search can be performed by, as previously mentioned, a raycast of objects within range. You can then, out of this set of objects, get the dot product of the player's "forward" direction (normalised), and the direction to the object (normalised).

As the dot product of two unit vectors is the cosine of the angle between them, you can say that if the dot product is above a certain threshold (say... 0.8) then you can say that the object is in front of the player.

In addition, if the object is definitely interactable, and is a door, trigger the interaction behaviour, and open the door.

Comment: If you found the door because it was hit by a raycast shot out from the front of the player, then the dot product check might be redundant: you already know the door is in front of the player. If it was fully off to the side or behind them then the ray would have missed it.

Comment: True, however, I only outline a very broad outline of methods to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For opening doors, performing a dot product with either the closed door or doorway is fine.

Usually for doors, you only want to open them if:

- They are close enough
- The player is facing the door
- The door is closed

A simple distance test for the first is fine. For the second, perform a dot product test between:

- The player's facing direction
- The vector going from the player to the centre of the door

Comment: Perform a dot product with what exactly? A directional vector from the center of the door? Separately with the normal direction of the front and back face of the door? I need some more information for this to be useful :)

Comment: In the edited answer above you say the dot product test is between the player direction and a vector going from the center of the door, but in the comment above you say to compare it with the front normal of the door. Which is it?

Comment: Also, in a non axis-aligned situation, how would I determine which side of the door the player is on?

Comment: To figure out which side of the door the player is on is essentially the same problem as figuring out which side of the player the door is on, just with the roles reversed. You'd dot the door-to-player vector with the door's forward. Positive means the player is "in front of" the door, negative "behind" (so if you have a convention that you orient your door's forward in the direction it opens, then positive means that the player would see it as a "pull" door and negative would be seen as a "push")

Answer (score 0):

Get a direction vector from the player to the door, and do a dot product between that and the direction the player is facing. The dot product is 1 if the two vectors are the same, and -1 if they are exact opposites. Thus, if the dot product is greater than some threshold (exactly what threshold looks good is up to you) then the player is facing the door.